# Enable certain users to be able to change the queues they are assigned to in Omni Supervisor

Tags: service-cloud-console, user-management, queue, omnichannel, omni-supervisor

From [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.omnichannel_supervisor_change_queues_skills.htm&type=5), Manage Users, Customize Application and Manage Public List Views are required for this (if changing queues created by other users).

Is there a neater, more 'least privilege' way of allowing certain users to be able to change the queues they are assigned to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked on this scenario with the Salesforce team internally and got feedback that what you are looking for is not currently available Out-of-the-box. Inherently, membership in Queues is a "User Administration" kind of privilege and that's reserved for specific people with Admin-like status.

The ability to limit a few users to be able to change the queues they are assigned to is on the roadmap(Spring'23 Safe harbor)